# Telerik.Web.UI reference version error

Tags: telerik

We are getting an error when we try to deploy our web application, 
Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2012.2.815.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'. (The X's are our token)

From what I have read in some other places there is supposed to be something in the web.config that we change. BUT in our web.config we don't see anything with the Telerik.Web.UI that states a version number?

We just have these in our httpHandlers

`

```
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
  <add path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>

  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>`
```

And this in our 
`<controls>
<add tagPrefix="telerik" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" assembly="Telerik.Web.UI"/>`

Where else would the version number be stated. We published and deployed our web app using Visual Studio 2012.
Another version of our web app worked and had the version 2012.2.815.40.dll in the bin.  But the version we are pushing out we are using 2011.1.519.40.

So it seems we need to add the newer version of the DLL to our recently pushed project. BUT when we put the 2012.2.815.40.dll
back in the /bin folder, we get a different error saying we need to reference the 2011.1.519.40.

What is our problem?  Where else, other than the web.config, would the version number be for our Telerik references????????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Telerik controls have the version attached to them, so if you have controls from different assemblies, you will see this behavior. Did you get it figured out by chance?

Comment: We did figure it out, surprisingly.  I will post the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Our answer to this was we had different version being pushed. Our version was older than the assembly that was generated.  We updated our Telerik versions, cleaned and rebuilt our projects, which presumably re-referenced the Telerik controls and did a clean push. 
This was very confusing at first, but the issue was because of the 2 different versions. We had a older version and the server had a newer version.
When in doubt. Update, rebuild, test and push. And test again